# Ubuntu Server - Internet not working on a specific network connection

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet

I run two home servers on which I've installed the Ubuntu 22.04 server. I also got a new network provider and a router, and one of the servers refused to just connect to the internet through that.

Setup 1.

- ISP: Jio
- Router: Company provided
- Server1: Internet Available
- Server2: Internet Available

Setup 2.

- ISP: Railwire
- Router: TPLink C6 AC1200
- Server1: Internet Available
- **Server2: Internet Not Available**

---

I cannot pinpoint if it's an issue with my router, my operating system or where if I can identify I can do something about it.

My question is with the same ethernat cable, same device internet works on one network but it doesn't work on the other.

Also with the router it works on one machine but not the other.

How can I narrow down this issue and provide more information to debug this?